# SwiftUI Text inside ScrollView, unable to scroll in both axes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a large amount of text, that I would like to display in a `Text()` view. If I wrap the view in a `ScrollView` I am able to scroll in either `.horizontal`, or `.vertical` direction.

However if I want scrolling in both directions, the layout is completely wrong. Almost as if there is a negative offset.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text = """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <PrettyXML>
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">
      <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
      </specVersion>
      <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:2</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Sample Renderer</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL></manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription/>
        <modelName>Test device</modelName>
        <modelNumber/>
        <modelURL></modelURL>
        <serialNumber>12354-12312789-123987129873</serialNumber>
        <UDN>uuid:12312311-1234-1234-1234-123456789011</UDN>
        <iconList>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-120x120x24.png</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-48x48x24.png</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-120x120x24.jpg</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-48x48x24.jpg</url>
          </icon>
        </iconList>
        <serviceList>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/ConnectionManager.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/ConnectionManager</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/ConnectionManager</eventSubURL>
          </service>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/AVTransport2.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/AVTransport</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/AVTransport</eventSubURL>
          </service>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/RenderingControl2.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</eventSubURL>
          </service>
        </serviceList>
        <presentationURL>http://10.0.0.1:80/</presentationURL>
        <dlna:X_DLNADOC>DMR-1.51</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
      </device>
    </root>
    """

    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
//        ScrollView(.vertical) {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach to this, or is it just a bug that has no workaround currently? My only other thought would be to use a wrapped `UITextView`, which will only allow vertical scrolling, but if there is a way to manually set the frame width to be as large as necessary, then allow the `ScrollView` to only scroll horizontally.

An incredibly ugly way of solving this would be:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    Text(text)
  }
}
```

However this only allows scrolling in one direction at a time which just feels unnatural.

It seems like this behaviour is also tied to updating views. Consider the following example which simulates an redraw:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var labelText = "Loading"

    let text = """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <PrettyXML>
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">
      <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
      </specVersion>
      <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:2</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Sample Renderer</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer></manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL></manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription/>
        <modelName>Test device</modelName>
        <modelNumber/>
        <modelURL></modelURL>
        <serialNumber>12354-12312789-123987129873</serialNumber>
        <UDN>uuid:12312311-1234-1234-1234-123456789011</UDN>
        <iconList>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-120x120x24.png</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-48x48x24.png</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>120</width>
            <height>120</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-120x120x24.jpg</url>
          </icon>
          <icon>
            <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
            <width>48</width>
            <height>48</height>
            <depth>24</depth>
            <url>/image-48x48x24.jpg</url>
          </icon>
        </iconList>
        <serviceList>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/ConnectionManager.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/ConnectionManager</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/ConnectionManager</eventSubURL>
          </service>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/AVTransport2.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/AVTransport</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/AVTransport</eventSubURL>
          </service>
          <service>
            <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:2</serviceType>
            <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl</serviceId>
            <SCPDURL>/xml/RenderingControl2.xml</SCPDURL>
            <controlURL>/Control/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</controlURL>
            <eventSubURL>/Event/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</eventSubURL>
          </service>
        </serviceList>
        <presentationURL>http://10.0.0.1:80/</presentationURL>
        <dlna:X_DLNADOC>DMR-1.51</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
      </device>
    </root>
    """


    var body: some View {
         ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            Text(self.labelText)
         }
         .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                self.labelText = self.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a smart way, here is a stupid one. You may add conditions to adapt different size class.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  let text = "" /// Your long multiline text

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
      ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
        VStack {
          Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.height)
          HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width)
            Text(self.text)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A better way is to add a viewModifier, which make things automatic.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  let text = "" // Your multiline text 

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { p in
      ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
        Text(self.text)
          .modifier(SimpleOffset(frameSize: p.size))
      }
    }
  }
}

struct SimpleOffset: GeometryEffect {
  var frameSize: CGSize
  func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
    ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: (size.width - frameSize.width) / 2, y: (size.height - frameSize.height) / 2))
  }
}
```

Here is the solution with pure alignments.

```
 var body: some View {

     ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
        Text(self.text).alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { (v) -> CGFloat in
            return (v[HorizontalAlignment.center] + v[.leading]) / 2
        }.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { (v) -> CGFloat in
            return (v[VerticalAlignment.center] + v[.top]) / 2
        }.frame(alignment: .center )
     }

}
```

The full code for the align method is like this :

```
            struct ContentView: View {


                let text = """
                <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <PrettyXML>
                <root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">
                  <specVersion>
                    <major>1</major>
                    <minor>0</minor>
                  </specVersion>
                  <device>
                    <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:2</deviceType>
                    <friendlyName>Sample Renderer</friendlyName>
                    <manufacturer></manufacturer>
                    <manufacturerURL></manufacturerURL>
                    <modelDescription/>
                    <modelName>Test device</modelName>
                    <modelNumber/>
                    <modelURL></modelURL>
                    <serialNumber>12354-12312789-123987129873</serialNumber>
                    <UDN>uuid:12312311-1234-1234-1234-123456789011</UDN>
                    <iconList>
                      <icon>
                        <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
                        <width>120</width>
                        <height>120</height>
                        <depth>24</depth>
                        <url>/image-120x120x24.png</url>
                      </icon>
                      <icon>
                        <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
                        <width>48</width>
                        <height>48</height>
                        <depth>24</depth>
                        <url>/image-48x48x24.png</url>
                      </icon>
                      <icon>
                        <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
                        <width>120</width>
                        <height>120</height>
                        <depth>24</depth>
                        <url>/image-120x120x24.jpg</url>
                      </icon>
                      <icon>
                        <mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
                        <width>48</width>
                        <height>48</height>
                        <depth>24</depth>
                        <url>/image-48x48x24.jpg</url>
                      </icon>
                    </iconList>
                    <serviceList>
                      <service>
                        <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:2</serviceType>
                        <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
                        <SCPDURL>/xml/ConnectionManager.xml</SCPDURL>
                        <controlURL>/Control/ConnectionManager</controlURL>
                        <eventSubURL>/Event/ConnectionManager</eventSubURL>
                      </service>
                      <service>
                        <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:2</serviceType>
                        <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport</serviceId>
                        <SCPDURL>/xml/AVTransport2.xml</SCPDURL>
                        <controlURL>/Control/AVTransport</controlURL>
                        <eventSubURL>/Event/AVTransport</eventSubURL>
                      </service>
                      <service>
                        <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:2</serviceType>
                        <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl</serviceId>
                        <SCPDURL>/xml/RenderingControl2.xml</SCPDURL>
                        <controlURL>/Control/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</controlURL>
                        <eventSubURL>/Event/Renderer/RygelRenderingControl</eventSubURL>
                      </service>
                    </serviceList>
                    <presentationURL>http://10.0.0.1:80/</presentationURL>
                    <dlna:X_DLNADOC>DMR-1.51</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
                  </device>
                </root>
                """


                var body: some View {

                     ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                        Text(self.text).alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { (v) -> CGFloat in
                            return (v[HorizontalAlignment.center] + v[.leading]) / 2
                        }.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { (v) -> CGFloat in
                            return (v[VerticalAlignment.center] + v[.top]) / 2
                        }.frame(alignment: .center )
                     }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still leaves the scroll view offset and unusable.

Comment: The second view modifier method works as I'd expect. It could benefit from some top and bottom padding on iPhone X/XS. I'll mark as accepted, although I don't think we should have to do this for two-axis scrolling!

Comment: I added a solution with pure alignments and that's should be what you expect.

Comment: Sadly the alignment guides didn't work either. The label is still very offset so can't be viewed.

Comment: I don't see your point. Can you repeat what I see in above full codes.

Comment: If you use a static string, like you do in your example, it works fine. But if you change the string later it lays out incorrectly. I've updated the original question with an example at the bottom. Replacing the `body` with your alignment issue presents the issue when run in the simulator or on device. I'm confident this is a bug in SwiftUI so I'm going to submit it as one.